# Highest gear much harder to pedal after repair - did the repair break something?

Tags: repair

I recently bought my bike in for repair and I got it back and I've noticed two separate issues that are causing me some concern and I wanted to ask this community what they thought of it.

1. The hardest gear is MUCH harder to pedal than when I first bought it in.  I'm talking some he-man strength to get this thing going.
2. When in the hardest gear and pedaling it feels like you can FEEL the chain, I don't know how else to describe it, but there is a feeling in the pedals.  This is only in the hardest gear, the other gears are ok.

Comment: What were the repairs? Is there any reason to believe that the drivetrain was altered?

Comment: What kind of drivetrain is it? And were you sure you were actually getting into the hardest gear before?

Comment: Yeah, sounds to me like the bike was adjusted such that you can now access all the gears, and you previously were not able to.

Comment: Batman's take seems most plausible. Also You realize you don't _have_ to use the hardest gear? Try an easier gear when starting out. The hardest gears are  typically intended to allow pedaling on descents.

Comment: Have you considered asking the bike repair place what they did?

Comment: Supposing Batman's theory is true; nevertheless, even the tallest gear on the average bike is easy to pedal once you get going. Also, the chain should move backwards with ease.

Comment: @Kaz - Opie doesn't say anything about the chain not moving backwards.  And it's not unusual for the highest gear to be perceive as "difficult" by some, when on level ground -- depends on the bike and the rider.

Comment: This question can't be answered without additional information. Nothing is known about the bicycle in question other than that it is multi-speed. I could speculate based on the assumption that it has a derailleur, and then it could turn out to have an internal hub transmission.

Answer (score 1):

If you only feel the chain when in the hardest gear, maybe the chain is rubbing somewhere or maybe the chain is being squeezed by the frame of the bike.

Put the bike in the hardest gear and turn it upside down. Pedal by hand while seeing if the chain has enough clearance everywhere. You may find your problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have derailleurs and not a hub gear, check that they haven't removed the chain and then not threaded it through the rear derailleur cage properly.

I've done this myself before (Images from Park Tools website):

[image: Chain routed incorrectly]

Note how the chain is going over the little bit of metal, rather than under it like in this image here:

[image: Correctly routed chain]

When pedalling, it just felt a bit weird. I could tell something was up, but it wasn't enough to stop you from pedalling along.

Comment: What you describe is vaguely possible, but any bike shop mechanic who would do this is totally incompetent, if only because 10 seconds of testing while on the repair stand would produce obvious symptoms.  (And Opie says that only the top gear has the problem.)